# Struggling with these Combination Questions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

So far combination has been the hardest chapter we've covered in my Data Management class. I somewhat struggled with permutation but at least I knew how to set the questions up. However, when it comes to combinations I'm completely lost. I'm going through my review sheet and I'm stuck on a couple of questions.

1.Given a deck of 52 cards, in how many ways can you select 4 cards such that

A) There is at least 1 Ace and at least 2 Kings

I couldn't get the answer for this so I looked at the answer key and I don't understand why the bolded part was included [Ace card-$\binom{4}{1}$] [King card $\binom{4}{2}$] **[Other-$\binom{44}{1}$]**

I know that we need to have a total of four cards, hence why we had to include the third one, but what I'm struggling with is how would I know that?

Edit: Reading the comments below I found out the answer for this question is incorrect. I will double check with my teacher and re-edit my post once I get the correct question.

B) All the cards are of different ranks

The answer key says [Ranks-$\binom{13}{4}$] [Suits-$\binom{4}{1}$ $\binom{4}{1}$ $\binom{4}{1}$ $\binom{4}{1}$]. I get where $\binom{13}{4}$ comes from, but what I don't get is why were suits included? The question asks us to select ranks, not to select ranks and suits.

2.In how many ways can you distribute cards from a deck of 52 cards so that

A) Alan receives 5 cards, Barbara receives 6 cards, Carl receives 7 cards, and Diana receives 8 cards.

Answer: $\binom{52}{5}$ $\binom{47}{6}$ $\binom{41}{7}$ $\binom{34}{8}$

B) One of the players receives 5 cards, another player receives 6 cards, a 3rd player receives 7 cards, a 4th player receives 8 cards

Answer: $\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{6}\binom{41}{7}\binom{34}{8} \times 4!$

Why was the answer for part B multiplied by 4!? What's the difference between these two questions?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: The stated answer for 1(a) is wrong unless you mean exactly one ace and exactly two kings among the four cards.  Typesetting tip:  `$\binom{13}{4}\binom{4}{1}^4$` produces $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{1}^4$.  You do not need to place each individual piece of a formula between separate pairs of dollar signs.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig, thank you so much for replying to my post. The way I have written is the way my teacher wants us to write it. The answer key for all the questions in the review package was written by him.

Comment: @Xander Henderson, I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Will make sure to do that next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: If you have another question. please ask another question, don't overwrite the old one.  All the comments are now irrelevant to the question.

Comment: The difference is, that if Alan gets six and Barbara gets five (and Carl & Diana get 7 & 8), then you don't count that in A, but you do count it in B.

Comment: @ saulspatz, I wasn’t going to edit it but when I saw the down vote I thought it was because I hadn’t edit the post to make sure I only had one question. For some reason what you wrote completely went passed my head. I’m going to in now and edit again since the user that helped me with the first question didn’t delete his/her post yet. Thank you so much for pointing that out to me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @  Gerry Myerson, thank you so much for replying to my post. I think I got it. I can't believe how easy it was. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Given a deck of 52 cards, in how many ways can you select 4 cards such that
>   A) There is at least 1 Ace and at least 2 Kings

"at least N" means you can have N ... OR MORE: 1 or 2 A's, 2 or 3 K's.
You can have: AKKK, AKKA, AKKx. Order is not important (x = any other rank).

AKKK: 4 ways to choose left out king, 4 ways to choose A = 16
AKKA: C(4,2) for the two A's, C(4,2) for the two K's = 6, and 6 * 6 = 36
AKKx: 4 ways to choose A, C(4,2) for the two K's, 44 for the X = 4 * 6 * 44
Grand total = 16 + 36 + 24*44 = 1108.

You need the 44 because in the last case, the last card can be any of the 44 non-A, non-K cards.

The given answer is for EXACTLY 1 A and 2 K's - not AT LEAST.

> B) All the cards are of different ranks
>   The answer key says [Ranks-C(13,4)
>   ] [Suits-C(4,1)*C(4,1)*C(4,1)*C(4,1)]. I get where C(13,4) comes from, but what I don't get is why we had to include the four suits. The answer asks us to select four cards, but we have 8 cards now (four from the ranks and 1 card from each suit).

Let's translate the expression into English.
Ranks: Choose 4 ranks for the cards: C(13, 4) ways to do that
Suits: Now, choose the suit for EACH OF THE FOUR CARDS: 4 ways for each one, multiplied together.

Comment: @T G, thank you so much. I completely understand what you wrote for 1. A and I'll make sure to bring up the mistake in class. As for 1. B, I still don't get why we have to choose the suits. Can't I just leave it at 13C4 since the question never asked us to list each of the suits?

Comment: The reason is that the suits matter.  Let's take a simpler problem: Just A and 2 of two suits (4 cards).  All ranks different, so you only have A-2 combination. But there is not just one way to do it: A-spades + any of 4 deuces, A-hearts + same, and so on: answer is therefore not 2C2 (=1), but 2C2 * 4 * 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hints for $2$:

1) In (a), we know the exact players who got a distinct amount of cards.  However, in (b), each of the players could get $5, 6, 7 \text{ or } 8$ cards, and since there are four people, how do we account for all combinations?

2) How many distinct (non-repeating) ways can we arrange the numbers $\{{5, 6, 7, 8}\}$?

Comment: I think I got it. Since we know Alan gets 8, Barbara 7, Carl 6, and Diana gets 5 for question A, we don’t know which one out of the four will get 8 cards, 7, 6, and 5 cards for question B. Player one can be anyone of them, player 2 again can be anyone of them, and so. And since we don’t know who’s getting what, we end up multiplying by four factorial because there are four ways each player can get any of the cards, right?

Comment: I thought I got it but apparently I don't. For B, shouldn't it be multiplied by four and not four factorial?

Comment: @Cece pick who got the 8 cards.  There are four options for who got the $8$ cards.  After having picked who got the 8 cards, *then pick who gets the 7 cards*.  Since we can't pick the same person again, there are *three* remaining choices for who gets the $7$ cards.  Continue by then picking who gets the six and then who gets the five cards respectively.

Comment: @JMoravitz, OMG, thank you. After reading your answer and thinking about what you wrote, I finally understood. I think I'm going to cry. Thanks a million.